# TFSBuildServiceHost service not running on TFS 2010 after updates to application tier

Tags: service

We've got a TFS 2010 installation with the build server, sql server and application tier on separate machines each.

The "Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host" service (TFSBuildServiceHost) runs fine until there is an update (e.g. Windows patches) that forces the application tier machine to reboot. In this case, the service on the build server is no longer running, and despite being set to restart after an error it does not do what it should, it simply stops with the following error message:

> Service cannot be started. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFundationServiceUnavailableException: Team Foundation services are not available from server http://....... Technical information (for administrator): HTTP code 503: Service unavailable [...]

Manually starting the service again works fine, so how can I make sure that I don't have to do it each time the application tier server reboots?

Thanks in advance,

G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I had this issue too, so I enabled recovery actions (on the TFS service `Recovery` tab):

First failure: `Run a Program` and pointed to a PowerShell script that notifies the TFS admin via SMTP and restarts the service.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I changed the entry on the Recovery tab so that I can verify after the next patch day whether this approach works. Nevertheless this seems to be a nasty workaround which actually shouldn't be necessary if the automatic restart would work as expected.